# Python run thread of class method one by one

Tags: python, multithreading, class, oop, python-multithreading

```
class rem:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        pass


class cycle:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        re = [rem1, rem2, rem3, rem4]
        th = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
        cy = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
        for i in range(3):
            for r, c, t in zip(re, cy, th):
                if c.get() == 1:
                    t = threading.Thread(target=r.start, daemon=True)
                    t.start()
            for c, t in zip(cy, th):
                if c.get() == 1:
                    t.join()
```

in above code re is object of class rem e.g re = [rem1, rem2, rem3, rem4]... i have declared it in my code

cy is another thing it has get method that gives 0, 1 it has also 4 obj cy = [c1, c2, c3, c4]

th is thread obj th = [t1, t2, t3, t4]

Now I want to run this code like
t1 thread
t1 finished 
t2 thread
t2 finished....

Here I try another method without thread

```
ispaused = False

class rem:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def temp(self):
        # doing somthing then
        self.stop()

    def start(self):
        global ispaused
        ispaused = True
        self.temp()
        pass

    def stop(self):
        global ispaused
        ispaused = False


class cycle:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        cy = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
        re = [rem1, rem2, rem3, rem4]
        for r in range(3):
            for re, c in zip(re, cy):
                if c.get() == 1:
                    re.start()
                    self.wait()

    def wait(self):
        global ispaused
        if ispaused:
            return self.wait()
```

I want to run code like run obj one wait for execution then run other object but

here I am getting error of RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

I can't use sleep() or while because Tkinter's loop is running.

Is it possible in this code or another way???

thanks in advance

Comment: If all thread should end before starting the next one, what the purpose of using thread ?

Comment: @azro yeah that right... but i tried to run direct class object but it will not run in one by one... in thread we can do that by join() method...if u know any other method u can suggest me